# Does "set -euo pipefail" have an effect on eval?

Tags: bash, shell, eval

Consider the following bash code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

Test() {      
  grep 'XXX' data
  echo 'test message'
}
```

`data` is an empty file existing in the same directory as the above bash script.

If `Test` function is invoked with the following code, it produces nothing to stdout.

```
Test
```

The reason is that grep command return exit status `1` since `data` does not contains `XXX`. So `set -euo pipefail` causes the bash script to exit immediately.

But if it is invoked with:

```sh
output=$(eval 'Test')
echo "output: $output"
```

It produes the following message to stdout:

```
output: test message
```

It seems that `set -euo pipefail` does not have an effect on `eval`. So grep command does not cause the bash script to exit.

Answer (score 3):

As long as bash is invoked as `bash`, you're mostly correct, except that it's the `$(...)`, not the `eval`, that suppresses `-e`. Beware though if it may be called as `sh` (or `bash --posix`): this is item #40 on [the list of changes between POSIX and non-POSIX mode](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/POSIX):

> 40. Enabling POSIX mode has the effect of setting the
>        'inherit_errexit' option, so subshells spawned to execute command
>        substitutions inherit the value of the '-e' option from the parent
>        shell.  When the 'inherit_errexit' option is not enabled, Bash
>        clears the '-e' option in such subshells.